# Showing that open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Show that open balls in $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic.

I'm trying to see if this works with examples. Suppose I have the open balls $ B_s = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid (x-1)^2+(y-1)^2 < \frac12 \}$ and $B_l = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid (x-5)^2+(y-5)^2 < 1 \}. $
If I define $t: \mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}^2, x \mapsto x+a$, where $a$ is a translation vector.

I would need have that all points of the smaller ball would map to the larger one. If I pick $a = ((1,1),(5,5))$ so the vector is the one shifting the center of the smaller ball to be in the center of the larger one. Now take $x = ((0,0),( \frac12,1)) \in B_s$. Applying $t$ to $x$ I have $$t(x) = ((0,0),(\frac12,1)) + ((1,1),(5,5)) = ((1,1),(\frac{11}{2},6)) \in B_l$$ so the point $x$ gets mapped correctly to the larger ball. However picking $x' =((0,0),(\frac32,1))$ I have $$t(x')=((0,0),(\frac{3}{2},1))+((1,1),(5,5)) = ((1,1), (\frac{13}{2},6)) \notin B_l.$$

What might be happening here? Is it the case that $t$ is not a suitable homeomorphism?

Comment: I think you should first map one into the other so their centers are the same, namely the origin; using polar coordinates is much, much easier.  Then you just multiply the radius of the smaller one to match the larger one.  Then the maps you have used are just a translation and multiplication by scalar.  Both are easy to prove are homeomorphisms, and the composition of two homeomorphisms is a homeomorphism.

Comment: If you change the radius of the balls, the homeomorphism should have that in account. Translations don't change the size of the balls. If you draw your balls and the function of translation should make this easier to understand.

Comment: First, there is a notational problem that I am unable to understand. What do you mean when you say $a = \left( \left( 1, 1 \right), \left( 5, 5 \right) \right) \in \mathbb{R}^2$? Notice that the elements of $\mathbb{R}^2$ are tuples whose entries are real numbers. In your case, all your tuples have entries as tuples. Something I don't understand. Secondly, what I could get from your attempt is that you want to form a homeomorphism by translation. But notice that the "sizes" of the balls are different and hence you would also require to stretch the smaller ball to the size of the bigger one.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh It seems I have to define the points as vectors in order to compute $x+a$? I cannot compute for example $(\frac12,1) + ((1,1), (5,5))$?

Comment: What is wrong in saying $\left( 4, 4 \right)$ is a vector? I now get what you wanted to convey. But, I feel it is only a tedious and confusing notation. Nonetheless, the problem with your solution is that you have missed the scaling part. Once you translate the smaller disc, you also have to make it of the appropriate size to get a homeomoprhism.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=rx+p$ maps $B(0,1)$ homeomorphically to the ball $B(p,r)$, where $p \in \Bbb R^2$ and $r>0$. So all open balls are mutually homeomeorphic. Works in any $\Bbb R^n$ BTW.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two open balls $B(p,r)$ and $B(q,s)$, the idea is to first move $B(p,r)$ to be centered at the origin with translation $x\mapsto x - p$. Now, you can scale the resulting ball to have the radius $s$ with scaling $x\mapsto \frac sr x$. Finally, move the ball to be centered at $q$ with translation $x\mapsto x + q$. If we compose all these maps we get $$f(x)= \frac sr(x-p) + q.$$
This map is bijective since you can just change the symbols to conclude the inverse is $$g(x)= \frac rs(x-q)+p.$$

It's a rather quick check that these are really inverses of each other.

Let us show that $f(B(p,r)) = B(q,s)$ and $g(B(q,s))=B(p,r)$.

So, let $x\in B(p,r)$, i.e. $\lVert x - p \rVert < r$. We want to show that $f(x) \in B(q,s)$, i.e. $\lVert f(x) - q \rVert < s$:

\begin{align}\lVert f(x) - q \rVert < s &\iff \lVert (\frac sr(x-p) + q) - q \rVert < s \\ &\iff \frac sr \lVert x - p \rVert < s \\ &\iff \lVert x-p \rVert < r.\end{align}

This shows $f(B(p,r)) \subseteq B(q,s)$. Analougously $g(B(q,s)) \subseteq B(p,r).$ Combine the two to get $$ f(B(p,r)) \subseteq B(q,s) \implies g(f(B(p,r))) \subseteq g(B(q,s)) \implies B(p,r) \subseteq g(B(q,s))$$ and analougusly $B(q,s) \subseteq f(B(p,r))$. This finishes the proof that $f,g$ are mapping $B(p,r)$ and $B(q,s)$ to each other.

Continuity of $f$ and $g$ follows since they are compositions of continuous functions. I leave that as an exercise.

Notice that the argument is general and works in any $\mathbb R^n$.